# Data migration for shared inbox possible?

Tags: email, exchange, imap

I just signed up for 2 new office365 licenses just for exchange. I am at the portion of the setup where it is migrating imap email to the users.

The 2 users have no problem connecting to imap to transfer all email. however for the shared inbox accounts support@domain.com and info@domain.com it says "no exchange online plan" and does not give me the option to migrate.

Is there a way to do it that I am not seeing?

Comment: Hopefully the link below can be helpful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/imap-migration-shared-email-accounts-unlicensed-in/9bc4f5a8-5499-4cb5-b06c-159b1c4e88c3

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way ended up being activating 2 licenses for the shared mailboxes, migrating and then de-activating the licenses.